# problem with if text in file matches count it as one c#

Tags: c#

```
    List<string> AllPublishers(List<Book> books)
    {
        List<string> publishers = new List<string>();
        foreach (Book book in books)
        {
            if (!publishers.Contains(book.Publisher))
            {
                publishers.Add(book.Publisher);
            }
        }
        return Publishers;
    }

    void PublishersList(List<Book> books)
    {
        string[] lines = new string[books.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < books.Count; i++)
        {
            lines[i] = String.Format("{0}", books[i].);
        }
        File.WriteAllLines(@"Publishers.csv", lines);
    }
```

Hey, only need the last segment for my project, so trying to finish it out. So the code above should print out only one Publisher if the publishers are the same, but instead it prints out all the publishers that it read from the data file.

For example:

Data given is (name of the book;publisher):

- Harry Potter;Bloomsbury Publishing
- Harry Potter;Bloomsbury Publishing
- Harry Potter;Bloomsbury Publishing
- Tom Sawyer;BlaBla

How it prints now is:

- Bloomsbury Publishing
- Bloomsbury Publishing
- Bloomsbury Publishing
- BlaBla

And how it should print:

- Bloomsbury Publishing
- BlaBla

Thanks for the help guys, hope you have a wonderful day/evening.

Comment: What is `knyga`? What is `knygos`?

Comment: Sorry, I translated it from my language just for this forum, so didn't see that I left 2 mistakes :/

Comment: Can you show the class definition for `Book` - at least the fields and properties?

Comment: Then I assume `books[i].` was meant to be `books[i].Publisher` ?

Comment: Your `PublishersList` has no reference to `AllPublishers` - what is their relationship? What did you mean it to be?

Comment: [`code`]
class Book
    {
        private const int BookIsValidFor = 2;
        public int ISBN { get; set; }
        public string BooksName { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string BooksType { get; set; }
        public string Publisher { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }

Comment: I don't see the `AllPublishers` method being invoked in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `PublishersList`, I'm guessing you need something like:

```
var publisherList = AllPublishers(books);
```

to actually get the publishers.  Then, use `publisherList` instead of `book` for the remainder of the method.

```
string[] lines = new string[publisherList.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < publisherList.Count; i++)
{
    lines[i] = String.Format("{0}", publisherList[i].);
}
File.WriteAllLines(@"Publishers.csv", lines);
```

As it currently stands, you are just iterating over the `books` list, which is why you get the same publisher output.

Comment: Oh my god dude, I can't thank you enough ^^ Thank you so much, hope you have an amazing day :)

Comment: No problem! Sometimes you just need a second set of eyes.  Feel free to mark this as the answer if it solved your problem :-)

Comment: Ahm, I am new to this site, so just asking: how to mark this as the answer? :D

nvm, got it :D

Comment: Good job, @ArnasAnatomik, and welcome to Stack Overflow!